# Android: run 2.0.1 app on 1.5 emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

In Eclipse, I have set my project's target build to 2.0.1 (right click on project folder -> Properties -> Android).
In my AVD manager I have a number of emulators - one for 1.5, one for 1.6 and one for 2.0.1.
How do I tell Eclipse to run the project (built to 2.0.1) on the 1.5 emulator?
The "Run configurations" menu gives me only the 2.0.1 emulator...

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (probably) cannot do so.  Try running a Win 7 program on Win 95, not compatible, libraries non-existant, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: It is possible, however, to run an app built to 2.0.1 on a 1.5 physical device (as long as the minSDKversion is compatible). Why not an emulator?

Comment: Why build against 2.0.1 when you want to run on 1.5?  Build against 1.5, save yourself a TON of heartache.

Comment: 2.0.1 supports multiple screen sizes while 1.5 does not. Mind sharing the heartache in 2.0.1?

Comment: the heartache is trying to get code compiled for 2.0.1 to run on a 1.5 device